# How to Fix those Radio Buttons? I need first one selected by default, but it's not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am trying to configure those radio buttons. When I run the app no one of those radio buttons is selected, while I need first one selected by default. I am using this code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, ListItem, Text, Radio, Right } from "native-base";

export default class RadioButtonExample extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      itemSelected: "itemOne",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <ListItem onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: "itemOne" })}>
            <Text>Daily Stand Up</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={this.state.itemSelected == "itemOne"} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: "itemTwo" })}>
            <Text>Discussion with Client</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={this.state.itemSelected == "itemTwo"} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

What should be fixed to make it work?

Comment: tried your code. Daily Stand Up is selected by default.

Comment: Have you tried on ios?

Comment: yes. In simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "checked" attribute, try it.

Comment: instead of itemSelected?

Comment: checked={this.state.itemSelected == "itemTwo"} see ->
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp